# Akka.net routee's parent

Tags: akka.net

It maybe a newb's question, but I can't find an answer both here and on http://getakka.net/docs/.
So, the question is - who is a Parent for a routee actor? The actual router's supervisor or a router itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some additional search, I guess I found the answer here - http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers#pools-vs-groups

> Routers are implemented as actors, so a router is supervised by it's parent, and they may supervise children.
>
> Group routers use routees created somewhere else, it doesn't have children of its own. If a routee dies, a group router will have no knowledge of it.
>
> Pool routers on the other hand create their own children. The router is therefore also the routee's supervisor.

In my case, it was a pool router, so a router will be an actual Parent of the routee.